# Nested Structure Initialization

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
     struct nodeout
     {
      int out;
      struct nodein{int in; }; 
     };

     struct nodeout* p;
     p=(struct nodeout*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeout));
     p->out=10;

     printf("%d",p->out);
 }
```

..Here is my code..How can I initialize the variable 'in' which is inside the structure nodein?

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: `prog.c:7:30: error: declaration does not declare anything`

Comment: Give it a name. `struct nodein{int in; };` --> `struct nodein{int in; } s_in;` then `p->s_in.in = 42;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did define `struct nodein` but did not define the `nodein` member for `struct nodeout`.

Do as following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    struct nodeout
    {
        int out;
        struct nodein {int in; } node_in; 
    };

    struct nodeout* p;
    p = (struct nodeout*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeout));
    p->out = 10;
    p->node_in.in = 5

    printf("%d %d”, p->out, p->node_in.in);
}
```